# unable to resolve ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am sending intent to a broadcast receiver like this.

```
Intent cpIntent = new Intent();
cpIntent.setClassName("com.android.contacts", "com.android.contacts.EABContactsAppReceiver");
cpIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
cpIntent.setAction(IMS_SUBSCRIBE); 
cpIntent.putExtra("contactid",contactid);
startActivity(cpIntent);
```

and at the receiver end I am accepting the intent as follows :

```
else if( intent.getAction().equals(ContactsListActivity.IMS_SUBSCRIBE )){ 
// this is a dummy event just to start the application
Log.d("ContactsAppReceiver", "IMS_SUBSCRIBE");
final String id = intent.getStringExtra("contactid");
Log.d(TAG,"id :"+id);
```

I have also declared the activity and the intent filter in `Manifest` file.

```
<receiver android:name="com.android.contacts.EABContactsAppReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- <action android:name="com.sec.android.app.sns.action.UPDATE_ACTIVITY" />
-->             <!--<action android:name="com.sec.siso.imsservice.IMS_SERVICE_READY_EVENT" />-->
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SYNC_STATE_CHANGED"/>
                <!-- <action android:name="com.sec.android.app.sns.action.UPDATE_MESSAGE" />
-->
                <action android:name="com.sec.siso.SUBSCRIBE"/>
                <action android:name="com.sec.siso.logs.SUBSCRIBE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

However I am still getting `ActivityNotFoundException`. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: do you add this to android manifest file   <activity android:name=".YourActivity" />

Comment: Ya.. i have added it in manifest as well. like the way shown.

Comment: can you paste logcat entries? I just wanna figure out where the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code, you're trying to start an activity instead of sending a broadcast. You should replace

```
startActivity(cpIntent);
```

with

```
sendBroadcast(cpIntent);
```

Comment: Exactly! Intents are used for 3 different purposes: start/communicate with Activity, start/communicate with Service, send Broadcast. These are completely different things and you can't mix them up.